# Image exceeds div and internal divs drop down when zooming-in

Tags: html, css, image

I'm still a begginer on CSS. Sorry if i upset someone ;)

I want to do a simple header with an image. My problem is that when I zoom in and out in browser, image exceeds or leaves space in the div.

My target is to do a header and a content div that contains multiple square divs. I want keeping 3 divs per 'row in the content when i zoom in, and also i want to resize header's image properly. But instead, image exceeds (or leaves-space) div limits and internal divs drops down and up when i zoom in and out.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="content">
        <div id="header">
            <img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/35k4gm0.png">
        </div>
        <div id="central">  
        <div id="squarelist">
            <div id="centersquare">
                <div class="lpsquare">
                    <div class="img_reference"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="lpsquare">
                    <div class="img_reference"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="lpsquare">
                    <div class="img_reference"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="lpsquare">
                    <div class="img_reference"></div>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    font-family: "arial";
}

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
}

#content {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin:0 auto ;
    width: 60%;
    min-width: 60%;
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto !important;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;        
    height: 216px;
    position:relative;
    background: #bbb;
}

#squarelist{
    width: 98%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#centersquare{
    margin:  auto;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;

}

.lpsquare{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
    width: 180px;
    height: 200px;
    background: black;  
    margin-left: 49px;
    margin-top: 45px;
}
```

There is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Katalhama/L8gZC/1/

(you might zoom-out to see it properly, cause image is big)

P.D: I want some like this http://warmuprecordings.bandcamp.com/

Thanks a lot :D

Comment: You say 'zoom-in' I guess you talking about the 'zoom' function built into the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page is all relatively sized, with various widths given in percentage. Ultimately, these will be relative to the size of the view, so they will be out of sync with each other.

It looks like you've applied a `width:100%` to `#header`, but it's the `img` inside of the `#header` that's too wide. Give `width:100%` to the `img` and it will stay inside the container.

Unfortunately, this will cause the image to shrink. You may want to reconsider the way you're building your header.

http://jsfiddle.net/L8gZC/3/

Comment: By the way i wanted image's shrink :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're simply looking for a percentage based approach. For example, on the class "lpsquare", instead of a fixed pixel width, try a percentage. So, for three divs in a row, make the width 33.333333%. Also, for the image elements, I think you will also need to apply percentage values to the width to make the fill out the fluids divs accordingly.

Then, you would need some responsive media queries to show a certain amount of "squares" per row depending upon screen width.

Comment: just using precentage is the right approach. You dont need media queries, 33% is 33% lol

Comment: i brought up the media queries because let's say for instance the site is now in a mobile portrait mode, i don't think you want to see three of those squares with images squished up side-by-side. so maybe, if desired, at mobile portrait width, he can make .lpsquare just go full 100%, or maybe even 50%